# sum function in pandas returns a wrong value

Tags: python, database, pandas, dataframe

before adding the line with comment, this code should returns a pandas dataframe with data:

```
            A  TSLA  KO  abg
Date                        
2020-09-14  1  1     1   0  
2020-09-11  0  0     0   0  
2020-09-10  0  0     0   0  
2020-09-09  0  0     0   0  
2020-09-08  0  0     0   0
```

however, after adding the line with comment in the `get_price` function, the sum function is returning a wrong value:

```
            A  I am test  TSLA  KO  abg
Date                                   
2020-09-14  1  9          1     1   0  
2020-09-11  0  0          0     0   0  
2020-09-10  0  0          0     0   0  
2020-09-09  0  0          0     0   0  
2020-09-08  0  0          0     0   0
```

I'm trying to sum all the rows in the dataframe and I don't know why the sum function returns the unwanted value. I wonder how to fix it and what causes the problem?

```
from collections import OrderedDict
import pandas as pd
import datetime as dt
import pandas_datareader as web
#====================================================
pd.set_option('display.max_columns', None)
pd.set_option('display.width', None)
pd.set_option('display.max_colwidth', -1)


cmaps=OrderedDict()
print(type(cmaps.items()))

#############
prev=10
endDate=dt.datetime.today().date()
sDate=endDate-pd.to_timedelta(prev,unit='d')

def get_price(tickers): #input is a list or Series
    result=pd.DataFrame()
    for i in tickers:
        try:
            df=pd.DataFrame()                
            df['Adj Close']=web.DataReader(i,'yahoo',sDate,endDate)['Adj Close']
            df['MA']=df['Adj Close'].rolling(5).mean()
            df.sort_values(ascending=False,inplace=True,by="Date") 
            df['Higher?']=df['Adj Close']>df['MA']
            df['Higher?']=df['Higher?'].astype(int)
            result['{}'.format(i)]=df['Higher?']
            result[tickers.name]=result.sum(axis=1) #this line causes problem
            
            
        except Exception as ex:  # no date column
            print('Ticker', i, 'ERROR', ex)
            print(df)
        
    return result
#--------------------------------------------------------------


test=pd.Series(['A','TSLA','KO','abg'])
test=test.str.replace('.','-')
test.name='I am test'
a=get_price(test)
print(a)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're computing the sum four times in every iteration of the for-loop. The sum is correct (1+2+3+3 = 9), because of the accumulation in the tickers.name column.

Just move the problematic line out of the for loop.